# How does one test the LAN speed without a server?

Tags: networking, lan, speed, speedtest, iperf

When I need to test the intranet speed I typically use `iperf3` at both ends (server and client) to check the flow rate between them. However recently when I tried some apps in the Play Store I noticed this app which claims to test the speed between the phone and the router without a server running

How can it do that? Is it testing the speed through ICMP packets or does it have some way to force the router to reflect all received messages to the sender?

[image: Wifi analyzer screenshot]